# Is it possible to create a vertical text direction for html email?

Tags: html, html-email

I need to create an html email. Is it possible to create a vertical text direction in the table of an html email, like this:

[image]

Please focus on the text "Belgium SABE.LIX ...." in vertical direction. Is it possible in html email?

Comment: Not sure how to do this without embedding an image (which you could generate dynamically)

Comment: You probably can, but email readers use crappy HTML engines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This text is vertical

```html
<svg width="50" height="300">

<text x="28" y="150" transform="rotate(-90, 28, 150)"style="text-anchor:middle; font-size:14px">This text is vertical</text>

</svg>
```

Comment: is svg tag supported in html email?

Comment: Did you get chance to try?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for as it rotates the text you just need to align it to the left or something.

```css
.text {
  width: 130px;
  height: 50px;
  -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
  /* Firefox */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
  /* Opera */
}
```

```html
<h4 class="text">text</h4>
```

Comment: "div" is not allowed in html email

Comment: Did this work? Or did the other answer? if so please accept one.

Comment: No problem. Good luck!